# Consistently remove a certain part of a file path?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a path `'app/resources/main/assets/templates/path/to/template'`, what is the best way to consistently remove `'app/resources/main/assets/templates'` from the path leaving only the `'path/to/template'`? At the moment I'm using splice and join the last 5 array items from using split but I may have some instances where the path could be longer so I would like to reliably be able to always remove `'app/resources/main/assets/templates'`

My version

```
var path = 'app/resources/main/assets/templates/path/to/template';
path.split('/').splice(-5, 5).join('/');
```

**but not great if** `path = 'app/resources/main/assets/templates/path/to/subfolder/template' //want only path/to/subfolder/template`

Comment: Remove the first 5 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a different perspective with Regex:

```
console.log( /templates\/(.*)/.exec(path)[1] );
```

Translation: Go until find "templates", when found capture everything after it.

To get previous folders aswell:

```
var newPaths = /(.*)templates(.*)/.exec( path );
console.log( newPaths[1] + 'templates' );
console.log( 'templates' + newPaths[2] );
```

Comment: So this outputs /app/resources/main/assets/templates, how would I remove that starting /?

Comment: @styler updated, added `\/` which removes the slash. Please use in code tags (`/`) or the literal name of the char when referring to single characters, it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can store base path in variable and then replace it in each path where you want, like so

```js
var BASE_PATH = 'app/resources/main/assets/templates';
var path = 'app/resources/main/assets/templates/path/to/template';
var result = path.replace(BASE_PATH, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer on the same trend as Kriggs. If the pattern you want to isolate always starts with `path/` you could subset the string like this

```
var path = 'app/resources/main/assets/templates/path/to/template';
var pattern = /path\//;
var FirstOccurrence = path.search(pattern);
path = path.substring(FirstOccurrence,path.length);
console.log(path);
```